# Why won't my javascript work on WordPress but fine when doing locally HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have this WordPress theme, and I can't get my jQuery scripts to work, I tried literally everything, no-conflict mode, including my own jQuery at the in footer.php, including jQuery in the header.php by enqueing WordPress' jQuery etc.

All of my scripts works fine, when not in a WordPress theme.

My URL is http://andreas-berg.dk/wordpress/ and my scripts are located at the very bottom of the script, right now I'm hard-coding jQuery into the footer.php, and removed it from the top, but no succes.

Any ideas on solving this? I've been pulling my hair on for hours now.

These are my scripts:

```
!function( $ ) { 

    $(".dropbutton a").click(function () {
        $("#dropdown").slideToggle();
    });

    $('.scroll-button').hide().fadeIn(1000);

    $(".slide").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).children().stop().slideDown(200);
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).children().stop().slideUp(200);
    });

    $('.nav-container a, .scroll-button a, .blocks a, .banner a, .text-right a').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 60
        }, 800, 'easeOutQuint');
        return false;
    });

    offsetValue = 60;
    $('body').data().scrollspy.options.offset = offsetValue;
    // force scrollspy to recalculate the offsets to your targets
    $('body').data().scrollspy.process();

    $('body').scrollspy({
        target: '.nav-container'
    });

}( window.jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JQuery is working fine. If you inspect your concole you will see some errors such as

```
**1068** errors stating: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'easeOutQuint'
```

for this you need to install [jQuery Easing Plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)

Check your errors, your JS isn't running simply because you have critical errors in your code.

Comment: Happens to us all! :D Nice site